# Behance API property name is number

Tags: c#, .net, json, naming-conventions, behance-api

I'm using a request link to get the projects of a user. It returns many following:

```
{
id: 123456,
name: "Deneme 2",
published_on: 1427213730,
created_on: 1427213604,
modified_on: 1427213730,
url: "https://www.behance.net/gallery/123456/trial-2",
privacy: "public",
fields: [
"Film"
],
covers: {
115: "abc.com/xyz.jpg",
202: "abc.com/xyz.jpg",
230: "abc.com/xyz.jpg",
404: "abc.com/xyz.jpg"
}}
```

but `covers` and `images` arrays are problematic. Their names are numeric, and when I use [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to deserialize them to a class that is identical to the fields on the returning JSON string, there occurs a problem because property names can't be numeric in C# classes, and when I change the names to alphanumerics (such as `BehanceImg_138` instead of only `138`), this time Json.Net can't match the field in the JSON string and BehanceImg_138 becomes null, although it's not null in JSON string. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Providing a link that contains your personal API Key publicly is not considered good practice. Please remove the link and include the JSON in your question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `JsonProperty` attribute to class properties. Like this:

```
public class BehanceData
{
  [JsonProperty("115")]
  public string _115 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Oh God, you are a life-saver! Thanks for your great help, it worked like a charm.